# How do I "bypass" the 'Password-Protected SQL Server Database' pop-up on Excel using VBA?

Tags: sql, excel, vba

I'm trying to create a VBA code on EXCEL where I can automate some data extraction from an SQL Server Database.

I'm accessing this SQL Server Table using the "PowerQuery" option on Excel itself. I have to enter an username and a password to access the data on "PowerQuery" and everytime I try to run my code on another computer, the 3 pop-ups below show up (they are in portuguese, but I'll try my best to translate them).

The first pop-up is regarding the "Privacy Levels". I have to check the checkbox and then, click on "Save"

[Privacy Levels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Di5A9.png) - *The level of privacy is used to ensure that the data are combined without interference from unecessary data. Incorrect levels of privacy may result in confidential data being leaked out of the trusted scope. More information on levels of privacy can be found here*

[  ]*Ignore Levels of Privacy check for this file. Ignoring the levels of Privacy may expose sensitive or confidential data to a unauthorized person*

Then, the second pop-up shows up, where I need to insert the User and Password for the table I'm extracting the data from:

[User and Password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ImVCD.png)

And finally, I have to "confirm" the last pop-up for the data to be extracted:

*It was not possible to conect to the data source using cripto-protected conection. To access this data source using a conection not cripto-protected, click OK*

[Criptography](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3fnLI.png)

I have this piece of code that I found online, but it doesn't work for my needs

```
    lin = 2
    STATION = ""
     STATION = "genericstation"
     sConnString = "Provider = sqloledb; " & _
                   "Data Source=" & STATION & "; " & _
                   "Initial Catalog= ;" & _
                   "User ID =user;" & _
                   "Password =password;"
```

Does anyone have any idea on how to bypass these pop-ups using a VBA code?

Comment: If the database server supports it, consider using Windows Authentication instead, which leaves all the password concerns on your Active Directory domain controller and leaves all connection strings without any hard-coded passwords anywhere.

Comment: Unfortunately it doesn't support Windows Authentication... And I've seen some examples were this could be bypassed, but for those cases, the query was done as a VBA code as well. But I do not know how to addapt a code from Excel PowerQuery into a VBA code